# Pycharm environment different than command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, osx-mavericks, pycharm

I am having an issue getting my Pycharm environment to match up with the environment that I have on the command line.  I recently removed python and reinstalled it via home brew.  The python in my path is pointing to `/usr/local/bin/python` I added `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to the beginning of my .bash_profile file and I can execute the following code just fine in the interperter on the command line.  However, when I add `/usr/local/bin/python` to the project python interpreters and run the below code I get the attribute error.  Can anyone shed some light on how I can get Pycharm to use the same environment as my command line?

```
import sqlite3
db = "mydb.db"
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
```

> AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'enable_load_extension'

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/104891. GUI apps don't read your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: ugh...seems like every version of OS X handles this differently...

Answer (score 30):

`.bash_profile` is being read by bash (your command line interpreter) only.
However if you want to preserve bash environment for PyCharm there is one
true Linux way.

Run PyCharm from your command line (from bash).
Thus environment variables will be inherited from bash to pycharm.
Read `$man` environ  for information on linux environment inheritance process.
So all you need is just launch `${PATH_TO_PYCHARM}/bin/pycharm.sh` from command line.
Or create launcher which invokes bash for PyCharm launching.

Thats it ! Hope that works for you.

Comment: It works when I run `./pycharm.sh` under the path {PATH_TO_PYCHARM}/bin. Do you know how to create a desktop launcher for Pycharm that also works well?

Comment: From @Sachin G. 's answer, it makes the life a bit easier to add the path in ~/.bashrc (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063361/how-to-run-pycharm-in-ubuntu-run-in-terminal-or-run): 
The question is already answered, Updating answer to add the PyCharm bin directory to $PATH var, so that pycharm editor can be opened from anywhere(path) in terminal.
~~~~~~~~~~~
Edit the bashrc file,
`nano .bashrc`

Add following line at the end of bashrc file
`export PATH="<path-to-unpacked-pycharm-installation-directory>/bin:$PATH"`

Now you can open pycharm from anywhere in terminal
`pycharm.sh`

Comment: I needed to make two changes: on the top of the file, change from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash -i` (interactive!). Bash is needed for `source`, interactive Bash is needed so `~/.bashrc` is source automatically. Optionally you can execute further scripts at the bottom

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PyCharm version 2016.3 and have noticed that your **PyCharm Terminal** is no longer providing the same default environment as your **MacOs Terminal** environment, it is a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164435) that should be fixed in 2016.3.1 - whenever it releases.  In the mean time, the following is a workaround that should 'default' all of your PyCharm projects back a more more MacOS-Terminal like PyCharm-Terminal:

**Create a ~/.bashrc file with the following contents:**

`source /etc/bashrc
source /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal
source ~/.bash_profile`

This *should* setup your PyCharm Terminal (*interactive bash session*) and make it similar to the MacOS Terminal (*login bash session*).  Once JetBrains patches and releases 2016.3.1, I recommend deleting this `~/.bashrc` file.  Hopefully this will get us all back to normal.

Comment: Unfortunately, this bug still exists as of 2017.1.2

Comment: still exists in 2024

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to source your script setting environmental variables (for example `.bash_profile`) by adding a line `. /path/to/script` into `PY_CHARM_INSTALL_DIR/bin/pycharm.sh`.

After that you can run pycharm using quick-lunch or whatever and you variables will be there.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: clarifying that this workaround is for **PyCharm 2016.3.0**

It's really recommended that you just run the following command

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

at the start of each terminal session until 2016.3.1 is released.

However, there is a workaround for this bug. The terminal script appears to have 2 function names reversed, so they must be renamed.

**You have to edit the app's terminal plugin script to do this, which is NOT recommended.**

On MacOSX, this is located here if PyCharm is installed globally (not sure where otherwise):

```
cd /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/terminal
```

Edit the 'jediterm-bash.in' file with the text processor of your choice.
If should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function load_login_configs {
  #       When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a  non-interac-
  #       tive  shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands
  #       from the file /etc/profile, if that  file  exists.   After  reading  that
  #       file,  it  looks  for  ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in
  #       that order, and reads and executes  commands  from  the  first  one  that
  #       exists  and  is  readable.

  if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then
     source /etc/profile
  fi

  if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
     source ~/.bash_profile
  else
     if [ -f ~/.bash_login ]; then
        source ~/.bash_login
     else
        if [ -f ~/.profile ]; then
           source ~/.profile
        fi
     fi
  fi
}

function load_interactive_configs {
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
       source ~/.bashrc
  fi
}

if [ `shopt -q login_shell` ]; then
  load_login_configs
fi

load_interactive_configs

# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
bind '"\e\e[C":forward-word'
bind '"\e\e[D": backward-word'
bind '"\e\O[C":forward-word'
bind '"\e\O[D": backward-word'

function generate_command_executed_sequence() {
   printf '\e\7'
}

export -f generate_command_executed_sequence


#generate escape sequence after command is executed to notify jediterm emulator
trap "generate_command_executed_sequence" DEBUG

if [ -n "$JEDITERM_USER_RCFILE" ]
then
  source $JEDITERM_USER_RCFILE
fi

if [ -n "$JEDITERM_SOURCE" ]
then
  source $JEDITERM_SOURCE
fi
```

Rename the following functions:

`load_login_configs` => `load_interactive_configs`

`load_interactive_configs` => `load_login_configs`

The final script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash

function load_interactive_configs {
  #       When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a  non-interac-
  #       tive  shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands
  #       from the file /etc/profile, if that  file  exists.   After  reading  that
  #       file,  it  looks  for  ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in
  #       that order, and reads and executes  commands  from  the  first  one  that
  #       exists  and  is  readable.

  if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then
     source /etc/profile
  fi

  if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
     source ~/.bash_profile
  else
     if [ -f ~/.bash_login ]; then
        source ~/.bash_login
     else
        if [ -f ~/.profile ]; then
           source ~/.profile
        fi
     fi
  fi
}

function load_login_configs {
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
       source ~/.bashrc
  fi
}

if [ `shopt -q login_shell` ]; then
  load_login_configs
fi

load_interactive_configs

# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
bind '"\e\e[C":forward-word'
bind '"\e\e[D": backward-word'
bind '"\e\O[C":forward-word'
bind '"\e\O[D": backward-word'

function generate_command_executed_sequence() {
   printf '\e\7'
}

export -f generate_command_executed_sequence


#generate escape sequence after command is executed to notify jediterm emulator
trap "generate_command_executed_sequence" DEBUG

if [ -n "$JEDITERM_USER_RCFILE" ]
then
  source $JEDITERM_USER_RCFILE
fi

if [ -n "$JEDITERM_SOURCE" ]
then
  source $JEDITERM_SOURCE
fi
```

Save and restart PyCharm and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in Mac OS X, graphic applications do not inherit your .bash_profile config. I'm posting the updated workaround for OSX 10.11 on how to set up environment variables at GUI level:

There is a useful repo called [osx-env-sync](https://github.com/ersiner/osx-env-sync) which reads ~/.bash_profile and sets the environment variables exported in it for GUI applications. After copying 2 files and running 2 other commands described on the github page, Pycharm can be launched in quick-start with global variables available as defined in the bash_profile.

[This](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469160-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-) link gives further background information.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just found a solution for this that works in PyCharm 2017.1.2

uncheck **Tools > Terminal > "shell integration"**

source: answer from @Federicojama near the bottom of the page
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208567485-Pycharm-terminal-is-missing-part-of-PATH

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot and totally forgot I'm working in a virtual environment! The `source /.profile` command needs to be run on the activated virtual environment in Terminal! I think some may have a hard day (or similar brain dysfunction to mine) and find this helpful.

Answer (score -1):

for me what worked was not running pycharm from the applications but from a terminal using chram . then it inherited all the env vars and paths

Answer (score -1):

I am using pycharm on OSX.  `Pycharm > Preferences > Terminal` had shell path  as `/bin/zsh`.
But this shell environment was not in sync with my other terminal emulators like iTerm.
For example, my conda environment was not getting initialized (not even the base environment).

Solution: Changing the shell path from `/bin/zsh` to `/usr/bin/env zsh` fixed things for me.
For `bash`, adding shell path as `/usr/bin/env bash` should work.