# Launch Pycharm from command line (terminal)

Tags: python, command-line, environment-variables, pycharm, sage

I want to try out PyCharm for sage mathematics development.  Normally I run eclipse to do sage development, but now I want to try it with PyCharm.

To launch eclipse with sage environment variables, in command line I normally do the following:

```
sage -sh
cd /path/to/eclipse
./eclipse
```

The first line loads the sage environment variables, the remainder launches eclipse.  How can I do the same thing for pyCharm?  (note I am using a Mac and Ubuntu for sage development; the commands above are agnostic to both OSes)

1. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715724/pycharm-environment-different-than-command-line) is close to the solution I am looking for, however I cannot find a pyCharm.sh anywhere.
2. [Link 2](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/working-with-pycharm-features-from-command-line.html): Jetbrains does not give clear instructions either.

Comment: In MacOS, you can launch PyCharm by typing "charm", it's the same behaviour as Yonathan Simson mentioned for Ubuntu.

Comment: JeBrains doesn't offer instructions on how to do this, even 2 years later. Which means, using PyCharm to run sudo-only scripts (like mouse hooks) isn't well documented by JB. I'm not impressed at all.

Comment: Anybody know how to do this on Windows in 2019??

Answer (score 274, accepted):

**Edit (April 2020)**: It seems that launcher script creation is now managed in Toolbox App settings.
See the [Toolbox App announcement](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2018/08/23/toolbox-app-1-11-whats-new/) for more details.

--

1. Open Application Pycharm
2. Find tools in menu bar
3. Click `Create Command-line Launcher`
4. Checking the launcher executable file which has been created in `/usr/local/bin/charm`
5. Open project or file just type `$ charm YOUR_FOLDER_OR_FILE`

Maybe this is what you need.

Comment: This is great because you can also open files or directories.

Comment: It turns out that by default on ubuntu you already have this file `/usr/local/bin/charm`. Though I could not have found it easily without your tip. Thanks!

Comment: Note, OSX also created the `charm` binary on install. Awesome !

Comment: I was able to find this command by searching the help within pycharm, but it appears to be disabled for me.

Comment: This has disappeared in the 2019.1 EAP.

Comment: @episodeyang It indeed disappeared. But you can change it manually to match a newer version. Find the location of the script (use `type -a charm`) then change the file paths in the python script. See my answer for the full script.

Comment: @botenvouwer this is now doable via the JetBrains Toolbox app. Their removal from specific IDEs reflects this design change.

Comment: @episodeyang Do you have any source to confirm this? I believe there must be a logical explanation, they would not just remove it as a 1 April joke would they :/. However, I can't find the option in the toolbox. There is a setting called `Generate shell scripts`, I'll give this a try to see what it does.

Comment: @episodeyang You are right, see https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2018/08/23/toolbox-app-1-11-whats-new/. I wil change my answer accordingly.

Comment: [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#launchers-macos-linux) there's some official description about this meaning for PyCharm 2019.3

Comment: How can I launch it detached from terminal ?

Comment: PyCharm 2021.1 (Community Edition) this option does not appear to me. So is it gone again?

Answer (score 28):

You're right that the [JetBrains help page](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/working-with-pycharm-features-from-command-line.html) isn't very clear. On OS X, you'll want to use the launcher at:

```
/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm
```

Or, for community edition:

```
/Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm
```

Unfortunately, adding a symlink to this binary wouldn't work for me (the launcher would crash). Setting an alias worked, though. Add this in your `.bash_profile` (or whatever shell you use):

```
alias pycharm="/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm"
```

Then, you can run commands with simply `pycharm`.

With this you can do things like open a project:

```
pycharm ~/repos/my-project
```

Or open a specific line of a file in a project:

```
pycharm ~/repos/my-project --line 42 ~/repos/my-project/script.py
```

Or view the diff of two files (they don't need to be part of a project):

```
pycharm ~/some_file.txt ~/Downloads/some_other_file.txt
```

Note that I needed to pass absolute paths to those files or PyCharm couldn't find them..

Comment: It looks like you can open a directory as a project as well using: /Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm /path/to/folder

Comment: I was trying your command. But I had to add a slash between Pycharm and CE.app. To get it working.

`alias pycharm="/Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm"`

Answer (score 23):

Inside the IDE, you can click in:

> Tools/Create Command-line Launcher...

[image: Create Command-line Launcher]

Comment: As pointed out in @Ami Mahloof's answer, it might be necessary to re-create this launcher after a PyCharm update (it was the case for me, PyCharm would launched but without opening the given path)

Answer (score 14):

## macOS

Easy solution without need for any paths:

```sh
open -b com.jetbrains.pycharm <file>
```

You can set it as alias for every-day easier usage (put to your `~/.bash_rc` etc.):

```sh
alias pycharm='open -b com.jetbrains.pycharm'
```

Usage:

```sh
# open current dir:
pycharm .
# open a file:
pycharm file.py
```

Comment: slightly shorter:       open -a pycharm <file>

Answer (score 11):

## Update

It is [now possible](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2018/08/23/toolbox-app-1-11-whats-new/) to create command line launcher automatically from JetBrains Toolbox. This is how you do it:

1. Open up the toolbox window;
2. Go to the gear icon in the upper right (the settings window for toolbox itself);
3. Turn on `Generate shell scripts`;
4. Fill the `Shell script location` textbox with the location where you want the launchers to reside. You have to do this manually it will not fill automatically at this time!

On Mac the location could be `/usr/local/bin`. For the novices, you can use any path inside the PATH variable or add a new path to the PATH variable in your bash profile. Use `echo $PATH` to see which paths are there.

**Note**! It did not work right away for me, I had to fiddle around a little before the scripts were generated. You can go to the gearbox of the IDEA (PyCharm for example) and see/change the launcher name. So for PyCharm, the default name is `pycharm` but you can change this to whatever you prefer.

## Original answer

If you do not use the toolbox you can still use my original answer.

~~For some reason, the `Create Command Line Launcher` is not available anymore in 2019.1.~~ *Because it is now part of JetBrains Toolbox*

This is how you can create the script yourself:

If you already used the charm command before use `type -a charm` to find the script. Change the pycharm version in the file paths. Note that the numbering in the first variable `RUN_PATH` is different. You will have to look this up in the dir yourself.

```
RUN_PATH = u'/Users/boatfolder/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/191.6183.50/PyCharm.app'
CONFIG_PATH = u'/Users/boatfolder/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2019.1'
SYSTEM_PATH = u'/Users/boatfolder/Library/Caches/PyCharm2019.1'
```

If you did not use the charm command before, you will have to create it.

Create the charm file somewhere like this: `/usr/local/bin/charm`

Then add this code (change version number to your version as explained above):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
import struct
import sys
import os
import time

# see com.intellij.idea.SocketLock for the server side of this interface

RUN_PATH = u'/Users/boatfolder/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/191.6183.50/PyCharm.app'
CONFIG_PATH = u'/Users/boatfolder/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2019.1'
SYSTEM_PATH = u'/Users/boatfolder/Library/Caches/PyCharm2019.1'


def print_usage(cmd):
    print(('Usage:\n' +
           '  {0} -h | -? | --help\n' +
           '  {0} [project_dir]\n' +
           '  {0} [-l|--line line] [project_dir|--temp-project] file[:line]\n' +
           '  {0} diff <left> <right>\n' +
           '  {0} merge <local> <remote> [base] <merged>').format(cmd))


def process_args(argv):
    args = []

    skip_next = False
    for i, arg in enumerate(argv[1:]):
        if arg == '-h' or arg == '-?' or arg == '--help':
            print_usage(argv[0])
            exit(0)
        elif i == 0 and (arg == 'diff' or arg == 'merge' or arg == '--temp-project'):
            args.append(arg)
        elif arg == '-l' or arg == '--line':
            args.append(arg)
            skip_next = True
        elif skip_next:
            args.append(arg)
            skip_next = False
        else:
            path = arg
            if ':' in arg:
                file_path, line_number = arg.rsplit(':', 1)
                if line_number.isdigit():
                    args.append('-l')
                    args.append(line_number)
                    path = file_path
            args.append(os.path.abspath(path))

    return args


def try_activate_instance(args):
    port_path = os.path.join(CONFIG_PATH, 'port')
    token_path = os.path.join(SYSTEM_PATH, 'token')
    if not (os.path.exists(port_path) and os.path.exists(token_path)):
        return False

    try:
        with open(port_path) as pf:
            port = int(pf.read())
        with open(token_path) as tf:
            token = tf.read()
    except (ValueError):
        return False

    s = socket.socket()
    s.settimeout(0.3)
    try:
        s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))
    except (socket.error, IOError):
        return False

    found = False
    while True:
        try:
            path_len = struct.unpack('>h', s.recv(2))[0]
            path = s.recv(path_len).decode('utf-8')
            if os.path.abspath(path) == os.path.abspath(CONFIG_PATH):
                found = True
                break
        except (socket.error, IOError):
            return False

    if found:
        cmd = 'activate ' + token + '\0' + os.getcwd() + '\0' + '\0'.join(args)
        if sys.version_info.major >= 3: cmd = cmd.encode('utf-8')
        encoded = struct.pack('>h', len(cmd)) + cmd
        s.send(encoded)
        time.sleep(0.5)  # don't close the socket immediately
        return True

    return False


def start_new_instance(args):
    if sys.platform == 'darwin':
        if len(args) > 0:
            args.insert(0, '--args')
        os.execvp('/usr/bin/open', ['-a', RUN_PATH] + args)
    else:
        bin_file = os.path.split(RUN_PATH)[1]
        os.execv(RUN_PATH, [bin_file] + args)


ide_args = process_args(sys.argv)
if not try_activate_instance(ide_args):
    start_new_instance(ide_args)
```

Answer (score 10):

I normally alias using built-in application launcher (open) from OS X:

```
alias pc='open -a /Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app'
```

Then I can type:

```
pc myfile1.txt myfiles*.py
```

Though you can't (easily) pass args to PyCharm, if you want a quick way to open files (without needing to use full pathnames to the file), this does the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Use Tools -> Create Command-line Launcher which will install a python script where you can just launch the current working folder using charm .

**Very important!**

Anytime you upgrade your pyCharm you have to re-create that command line tool since its just a python script that points to a pyCharm configuration which might be outdated and will cause it to fail when you attempt to run `charm .`

Comment: Indeed, I had to re-create the launcher every time I updated PyCharm for it to work again.

Comment: I like to have a command line launcher, but I suppose this is the advantage of just letting Toolbox do it for you!

Answer (score 3):

To open PyCharm from the terminal in Ubuntu 16.04, cd into

```
{installation home}/bin
```

which in my case was

```
/home/nikhil/pycharm-community-2018.1.1/bin/
```

and then type:

```
./pycharm.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

## On Mac OSX

*Update 2019/05* Now this can be done in the JetBrains Toolbox app. You can set it once with the Toolbox, for all of your JetBrain IDEs.

---

As of *2019.1 EAP*, the `Create Commmand Line Launcher` option is not available in the Tools menu anymore. My solution is to use the following alias in my bash/zsh profile:

Make sure that you run `chmod -x ...../pycharm` to make the binary executable.

```sh
# in your ~/.profile or other rc file to the effect.

alias pycharm="open -a '$(ls -r /Users/geyang/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/**/PyCharm*.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm)'"
```

Comment: The release version of 2019.1 has the `Create Command Line Launcher` menu item again.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to the directory on the terminal `cd [your directory]`

[Navigate to the directory on the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdnpG.png)

use `charm .` to open the project in PyCharm

***Simplest and quickest way to open a project in PyCharm***

Answer (score 1):

Useful information for some:

On Linux, installing PyCharm as a snap package automatically creates the command-line launcher named pycharm-professional, pycharm-community, or pycharm-educational. The Tools | Create Command-line Launcher command is therefore not available.

Answer (score 1):

Steps for someone using zsh on Mac:

1. emacs ~/.zshrc&
2. Put this in zshrc---> alias pycharm="/Applications/PyCharm\CE.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm"
3. source ~/.zshrc
4. Launch by typing pycharm in command window

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to open pycharm or anything else from terminal is to create a symbolic link, like the following:

sudo ln -s /home/name/Downloads/pycharm-professional-2023.2.3/pycharm-2023.2.3/bin/pycharm.sh* /usr/local/bin/charm

now restart the terminal and in the next session you will be able to use the word 'charm' in the terminal to open 'pycharm .' from it.

[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gImH.png)

Answer (score 0):

The included utility that installs to `/usr/local/bin/charm` did not work for me on OS X, so I hacked together this utility instead. It actually works!

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  echo ""
  echo "Usage: charm <filename>"
  exit
fi
FILENAME=$1

function myreadlink() {
  (
  cd $(dirname $1)         # or  cd ${1%/*}
  echo $PWD/$(basename $1) # or  echo $PWD/${1##*/}
  )
}

FULL_FILE=`myreadlink $FILENAME`;

/Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm $FULL_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update: My answer no longer works as of PyCharm 2018.X

On MacOS, I have this alias in my bashrc:

```
alias pycharm="open -a /Applications/PyCharm*.app"
```

I can use it like this: `pycharm <project dir or file>`

The advantage of launching PyCharm this way is that you can open the current dir in PyCharm using `pycharm .` (unlike `/Applications/PyCharm*.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm .` which opens the PyCharm application dir instead)

---

Update: I switched to JetBrains Toolbox to install PyCharm. Finding PyCharm has gotten a bit more complex, but so far I was lucky with this monster:

```
alias pycharm="open -a \"\$(ls -r  /Applications/apps/PyCharm*/*/*/PyCharm*.app | head -n 1 | sed 's/:$//')\""
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing on kubuntu, I found that my pycharm script in `~/bin/pycharm` was just a desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PyCharm Community Edition
Icon=/snap/pycharm-community/79/bin/pycharm.png
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop /snap/bin/pycharm-community %f
Comment=Python IDE for Professional Developers
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm-ce
```

Obviously, I could not use this to open anything from the command line:

```
$ pycharm setup.py
/home/eldond/bin/pycharm_old: line 1: [Desktop: command not found
/home/eldond/bin/pycharm_old: line 4: Community: command not found
```

But there's a hint in the desktop entry file. Looking in `/snap/pycharm-community/`, I found `/snap/pycharm-community/current/bin/pycharm.sh`. I removed `~/bin/pycharm` (actually renamed it to have a backup) and then did

```
ln -s /snap/pycharm-community/current/bin/pycharm.sh pycharm
```

where again, I found the start of the path by inspecting the desktop entry script I had to start with.

Now I can open files with pycharm from the command line. I don't know what I messed up during install this time; the last two times I've done fresh installs, it's had no trouble.

Answer (score 0):

`open /Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app/` opens up the primary Pycharm Dialogue box to choose the project..

worked for me with `macOS 10.13.6` & `Pycharm 2018.1`

Answer (score 0):

**pycharm download & Open in UBUNTU**

**Download:**

- download pycharm linux version here : https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux
- Extract the download the downloaded tar file using :  tar -xvf pycharm-Example-tar.gz

**Open:**

1. Navigate to bin directory in the extracted folder.
2. run : ***./pycharm.sh***

Answer (score 0):

you can include following command in your script

```
root@aachutha-Inspiron-N5010:~# pycharm-community &
```

[1] 5698

Answer (score 0):

Now you can generate shell script in jetbrains-toolbox, follow this guide:

### [image]

### [image]

[image]

Now you can execute it through the shell:

```
~/.local/bin/jetbrains-pycharm
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023.3 version, To run PyCharm from the shell, use the open command with the following options:

Mac OS:

```
open -na "PyCharm.app"
```

For community Version:

```
open -na "PyCharm CE.app"
```

None of the above works, go to the /Applications directory and check the {pycharm name} then try

```
 open -na "{pycharm name}"
```

> If PyCharm is not in the default /Applications directory, specify the
> full path to it.

For more info, Refer to this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#standalone).

Answer (score 0):

On Unix based systems (linux), you can make it code like vscode: "code ."

ref: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2023.3/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#standalone

1. Open the Application Pycharm
2. Find tools in menu bar
3. Click Create Command-line Launcher
4. `ln -s <pycharm installation dir>/bin/pycharm.sh /usr/local/bin/charm` #or create an alias pointing to pycharm.sh called charm
   `echo "alias charm=<pycharm installation dir>/bin/pycharm.sh> >> ~/.bashrc"`
5. Open project or file just type "`charm YOUR_FOLDER_OR_FILE`" or "`charm .`"

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me on my 2017 imac macOS Mojave (Version 10.14.3).

1. Open your ~/.bash_profile:
   `nano ~/.bash_profile`
2. Append the alias:
   `alias pycharm="open /Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app"`
3. Update terminal:
   `source ~/.bash_profile`
4. Assert that it works:
   `pycharm`

Answer (score -1):

#### Via Terminal (Linux)

---

Create a function with bash.

```
charm() { /usr/local/bin/charm; }
export charm
```

#### Via Pycharm

> 1. Go into Pycharm
> 2. Tap Double Shift (Shift + Shift)
> 3. Search For **Create Command-line Launcher**
> 4. Type in **Command-line Launcher**: /usr/local/bin/charm
> 5. Click **Ok**

Answer (score -2):

You can launch `Pycharm` from Mac terminal using the open command. Just type `open /path/to/App`

```
Applications$ ls -lrt PyCharm\ CE.app/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x@ 71 amit  admin  2414 Sep 24 11:08 lib
drwxr-xr-x@  4 amit  admin   136 Sep 24 11:08 help
drwxr-xr-x@ 12 amit  admin   408 Sep 24 11:08 plugins
drwxr-xr-x@ 29 amit  admin   986 Sep 24 11:08 license
drwxr-xr-x@  4 amit  admin   136 Sep 24 11:08 skeletons
-rw-r--r--@  1 amit  admin    10 Sep 24 11:08 build.txt
drwxr-xr-x@  6 amit  admin   204 Sep 24 11:12 Contents
drwxr-xr-x@ 14 amit  admin   476 Sep 24 11:12 bin
drwxr-xr-x@ 31 amit  admin  1054 Sep 25 21:43 helpers
/Applications$
/Applications$ open PyCharm\ CE.app/
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine in macOS 10.13.6