# Opening Pycharm from terminal with the current path

Tags: python, bash, command-line, pycharm

If you give in the command "atom ." in the terminal, the Atom editor opens the current folder and I am ready to code.

I am trying to achieve the same with Pycharm using Ubuntu: get the current directory and open it with Pycharm as a project.

Is there way to achieve this by setting a bash alias?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch Pycharm from command line (terminal)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133861/launch-pycharm-from-command-line-terminal)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PyCharm can be launched using the `charm` command line tool (which can be installed while getting started with PyCharm the first time).

`charm .`

Comment: You can configure it as explained here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/opening-files-from-command-line.html @salman

Comment: it opens PyCharm but the problem I am facing is, when I close terminal then PyCharm exited automatically.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

```
pycharm-community .
```

Comment: or `pycharm-professional .` for those using the Professional Edition

Comment: searched again for this, found my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
alias atom_pycharm='~/pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh .'
```

Maybe you installed it to a different path, though - `locate` your `pycharm.sh` file and modify accordingly.

You have the usual bash tricks: if you want to run in the background, append an `&`, redirect stdout/stderr where you want etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
open -na "PyCharm CE.app" .
```

worked for me in MacOS & PyCharm Community edition

Comment: This worked for me in mac. I also added an alias in `.zshrc` to make it easier:

`alias pycharm="open -na PyCharm\ CE.app"`

For more customization, see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#toolbox

Answer (score 0):

For me its:

pycharm.bat .

but I had to add an Environment Variable first using the path where pycharm.bat is located. In my case it was:

C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.1\bin

(how to add an Environment Variable)
Windows
https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/

Ubuntu
https://hackprogramming.com/2-ways-to-permanently-set-path-variable-in-ubuntu/

I'm using Pycharm Community Edition 2019.3.1 and for the life of me I couldn't find the "Command line launcher" everyone else is talking about so I had to resort to this method.

This was for Windows but hopefully it will give you some insight on figuring it out on Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way old but I just had to do this.
I created an alias for pycharm in my bashrc file.

```
alias pycharm='pycharm.sh $(pwd)'
```

nesting the pwd command allowed me to use the current directory I am in.

Since jetbrains says to use

```
pycharm.sh /your/dir
```

source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/opening-files-from-command-line.html

Answer (score -2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQzJ5.jpg)

Open your terminal and type:$ cd Desktop/pycharm-community

Comment: This is what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58060943/1364007) already said.