# Set paths for JetBrains PyCharm [Linux]

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I run Python program which uses couple of source paths on runtime.

I put these rows on my `/.bashrc` file:

```
source home/raphael/kaldi/aspire/s5/cmd.sh
source home/raphael/kaldi/aspire/s5/path.sh
```

So when I'm running from terminal everything works fine and Python manage to locate paths.

However when I'm trying to run through PyCharm for DEBUG purposes mostly it seems that PyCharm can't locate the paths.

Is there anyway to add the paths manually for PyCharm or make it read `/.bashrc` file. What I am missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pycharm environment different than command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715724/pycharm-environment-different-than-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the options available in the `Run/Debug Configuration` settings (Run > Edit Configurations...)

You can set environment variables individually (such as $PATH), or at the bottom is a section to define external tools (scripts) to be run when your Python code is run or debugged. From that sub-section, you could set your bash scripts to be run each time you start debugging.

Alternatively, see if using `os.environ` would work for your project. Check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.environ) for more information.