# PyCharm executables for solver not found

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, pyomo, glpk

Running a python+pyomo optimization with PyCharm results in the error, that the executable cannot be found for the solver. I tested it with glpk and gurobi.

The projekt interpreter is set to my conda path. In PyCharm, I can see, that glpk is installed in that path, too. I also verified that by showing the content of the anaconda path on my machine.

Running the same code in the terminal outside of PyCharm, does not lead to an error.

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04. with PyCharm 2018.1 Community Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying the terminal in PyCharm, I also got the code to run. So I checked the different environment variables. The PATH variable is different to the terminal PATH variable in the Python console. It seems to be similar to [that stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715724/pycharm-environment-different-than-command-line). After adding the missing PATHs by starting PyCharm from the terminal, glpk and gurobi can be found.

Actually, I still do not quite get, why PyCharm is not using `.bashrc` by default.