# Python, Pycharm - missing environment variables in os.environ

Tags: python, pycharm

Using Python 3.6, PyCharm 2019.3.1 CE, 64-bits Ubuntu 18.04

I have an environment variable that is accessed fine when running my python script from the command line, but does not show up when running with PyCharm.

This is the script:

```
import os
print(os.environ.get("GENICAM_GENTL64_PATH"))
```

From the terminal, this is my output:

```
:/usr/lib/ids/cti
```

While with PyCharm, this is my output:

```
None
```

What is happening here? Why does the environment variable not show up when running with PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run python from your terminal, the python script inherits the environment variables from the shell, which in turn gets `GENICAM_GENTL64_PATH` through a startup script in /etc/profile.d. (see [docs](https://www.stemmer-imaging.com/media/uploads/cameras/avt/10/100692-Allied-Vision-VIMBA-Release-Notes-Linux.txt)).

In contrast, when you start the script from PyCharm, there is no shell - PyCharm starts the python process itself - so you won't have the environment variables that populated by /etc/profile.d.

You can solve it by launching PyCharm from your terminal, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715724/pycharm-environment-different-than-command-line).